# How can I write a test that fails a "requires(...)" in Solidity?

Tags: truffle, testing

If calling a function in a contract would result in a failed `require` the whole test passes, even if the asserts are incorrect. This is extremely confusing. Look at the simple example below, which actually passes when it should obviously fail.

```
function testSomeFuncThatRequires() public {
    Assert.equal(uint(1), uint(2), "What the hell");
    require(1 > 2);
  }
```

If you remove the `require(1 > 2)`, then the test fails as expected. 
I am using `truffle test` to run my tests.

What am I doing wrong? Do most people just test their contracts with JavaScript? Seems like the problem is avoidable with JS.

Comment: How are you setting the rest of your file up? I tried the above and it did throw as expected with the addition of `require(1>2)`.

Comment: Dang... maybe I am using an old version of something? I don’t know what it would be though since I just installed everything for Ethereum for the first time last week. I just did truffle init and went from there. I’ll add a copy of my whole test file ASAP.